# What are the different types of face recognitions the dlib has?

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

Can i know what are all the face recognitions the **dlib** has to offer us. This is  in the case of face landmarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many landmark detectors dlib has to offer us. Mostly, The first one is:
**68-point landmark detectors:** This pre-trained landmark detector identifies 68 points ((x,y) coordinates) in a human face. These points localize the region around the eyes, eyebrows, nose, mouth, chin and jaw.
The second one is:**5 point landmark detector:** To make things faster than the 68 point detector, dlib introduced the 5 point detector which assigns 2 points for the corners of the left eye, 2 points for the right eye and one point for the nose. This detector is most commonly used for alignment of faces.
There is a good article in gfg:[Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/opencv-facial-landmarks-and-face-detection-using-dlib-and-opencv/)
There is also another link : [good explanation with examples.](https://analyticsindiamag.com/step-by-step-guide-to-stabilize-facial-landmarks-in-a-video-using-dlib/)